# Can you let Preview (the app) cycle through anything?

Tags: preview, slideshow

This is related to this question:

[How to start a slideshow on the Mac super quick and easy?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26449/how-to-start-a-slideshow-on-the-mac-super-quick-and-easy/26526#26526)

Basically, I wonder why even in Snow Leopard, I double click on a photo in Finder, and Preview will show that photo, but no arrow key can let me see the next photo in the folder?   Is there a way at all?  Or will the next version of Mac OS X add it, I wonder -- is it that counter-intuitive to show the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As more or less already answered in the question you linked to, you can get the effect you want by

1. selecting the first file, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> to open Quick Look and use the cursor key to jump to the next one
2. selecting all the relevant files (pictures) and pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> to enter Quick Look
3. selecting all the relevant files (pictures) and pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open them in one Preview window
4. command-doubleclicking the folder containing the pictures to open a new finder window followed by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to switch the new window to Coverflow mode
5. command-doubleclicking the folder containing the pictures to open a new finder window followed by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to switch the new window to Column mode and just step through the files to get the content displyed in preview mode in the last column.

Given the different options already available to get the desired result, do we really need another one?

PS: Technically speaking, Preview.app is just an application able to display pictures and PDFs. It doesn't know anything about a *next* file in a folder.

Comment: 1.) is wrong. Cursor keys only work on the same line. In icon mode, they would stop working after 3-4 pics. 2 and 3) require explicit selection of all pictures. 4 and 5) are just ridiculously convoluted. Not to mention both would only show you a slightly bigger thumbnail (or maybe even smaller depending on settings) than the icon view thumbnails. So yes, another method IS necessary